# How to rebind datasource to a winform DataGridView Combobox column?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView in winform with 2 combo box columns: 1) Companies, 2) Accounts.
I want to update the accounts combo box according to the selected company.
I have this code:

```
void recipientsDataGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                cb.SelectedValueChanged -= new EventHandler(companyCombobox_SelectedValueChanged);
                cb.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(companyCombobox_SelectedValueChanged);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private void companyCombobox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentCell = recipientsDataGrid.CurrentCellAddress;
            if (currentCell.X == 3)
            {
                var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                int companyId = sendingCB.SelectedValue.ToInt();
                DataTable dtAccounts = m_CustomersFunctions.GetCompanyAccounts(companyId);

                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboAccounts = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)recipientsDataGrid.Rows[currentCell.Y].Cells["Account"];
                cboAccounts.ValueMember = "account_id";
                cboAccounts.DisplayMember = "AccountName";
                cboAccounts.DataSource = dtAccounts;

                int defaultAccountId = (from row in dtAccounts.AsEnumerable()
                                        where row.Field<string>("AccountName").EndsWith("*")
                                        select row.Field<int>("account_id")).FirstOrDefault();
                if (defaultAccountId > 0)
                    cboAccounts.Value = defaultAccountId;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It works fine in the first time I select a company, but when I change the company and try to update the data source for the accounts combo box I'm getting an error:

[image]

I tried to add the items manualy and not with a DataSource, and I got the same error.
How can I fix it ?
please...

Answer (score 3):

Try to clear the value of accounts cell before rebind it, like this:

```
private void companyCombobox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var currentCell = recipientsDataGrid.CurrentCellAddress;
        if (currentCell.X == 3)
        {
            var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            int companyId = sendingCB.SelectedValue.ToInt();
            DataTable dtAccounts = m_CustomersFunctions.GetCompanyAccounts(companyId);

            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboAccounts = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)recipientsDataGrid.Rows[currentCell.Y].Cells["Account"];
            cboAccounts.Value = null; //Add this code
            cboAccounts.ValueMember = "account_id";
            cboAccounts.DisplayMember = "AccountName";
            cboAccounts.DataSource = dtAccounts;

            int defaultAccountId = (from row in dtAccounts.AsEnumerable()
                                    where row.Field<string>("AccountName").EndsWith("*")
                                    select row.Field<int>("account_id")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (defaultAccountId > 0)
                cboAccounts.Value = defaultAccountId;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in vb.net .

Not sure if my solution is good, but it works for me.

Briefly: I create a new temporary "DataGridViewComboBoxCell" object, I assign the "DataSource" and the "Value" (which must belong to "DataSource" !!! otherwise the error "value is not valid" comes out) and assign the new object to correct cell in my "DataGridView" main object, like this:

```
Dim oDataGridViewComboBox As New DataGridViewComboBox With {
    .DataSource = MyDataSource
    .Value = MyCorrectValueContainedInDataSource
}
oMyDataGridView.Rows(iLineOfComboBox).Cells("ComboBoxColumnName") = oDataGridViewComboBox
```

The error "value is not valid" is thrown because the ComboBox value is not included among those present in "DataSource".

P.S.: Sorry, I don't know C# ... but the problem is the same, and I have found this post during a search of solution.